# Lazy loading leads to undefined data in Ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm using ember.js for a week and ran into a problem concerning ember-data and ember.js. I have a simple 1:N-relationship on a model called `User`. `User` hasMany `Slots` which are defined by a `start_time` and an `end_time`.

In a component which is called `slots-per-day` all slots of a given user are rendered filtered by day with the following js code:

```
  /* ... rest of component.js of slots-per-day ... */
  filteredSlots: Ember.computed('user', function() {
    let time = moment();
    return this.get('user.slots').filter( (slot) => {
      let left = moment(time).startOf('day');
      let right = moment(time).endOf('day');
      let start_time = moment(slot.get('start_time'));
      let end_time = moment(slot.get('end_time'));
      console.debug(slot.get('start_time'));

      return start_time.isBetween(left, right) || end_time.isBetween(left, right);
    });
  })
  /* ... rest of component.js of slots-per-day ... */
```

There are several problems I faced with different approaches:

1. Using the code above the filteredSlots-property is only evaluated **once**. The underlying storage is in an *undefined* state, since the `console.debug` outputs `undefined` but the amount of slots is just right. So i guess ember-data has loaded the array for the slots, but *forget* to load the rest of data. If I do a transition to the same route all data is displayed properly and `console.debug` returns different moment.js-dates.
2. If I add `user.slots` to the dependency list of that property, it is evaluated **twice**. Both evaluations lead to the same debug output as in (1): `undefined`.
3. If I add `user.slots.@each.start_time`, the property is evaluated the amount of components on that page times the amount of slots (which is very slow). Despite the fact, that it is slow, it works and renders the data correctly.

So the question is: How do I preload all data in ember-data, before the components get rendered?

**EDIT**:

I also tried with promises:

```
  /* SlotRoute ... */    
  setupController(controller, model){
    this._super(controller, model);
    controller.set('time', this.get('time'));
    controller.set('users', model.users);
    controller.set('timeScope', this.get('timeScope'));
  },

  users: Ember.computed('time', function() {
    return this.store.query('user', {
      slots: {
        time: this.get('time').toString(),
        timeScope: this.get('timeScope')
      }
    });
  }),

  model(params) {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      users: this.get('users'),
      slots: this.store.get('slots')
    });
  },
  /* ... */
```

No change in positions (1), (2) and (3) of the list above.

Answer (score 0):

Number 3 is the correct way to write up your computed property, especially with an async relationship. You will have to pay the price somewhere, if you want to pay it during transition you can use `afterModel` assuming you are fetching user using the `model` hook.  You can also use `afterModel`/`beforeModel` of that particular route if it's loaded somewhere else.

The route

```
model(params){
  return this.store.find('user', 1);
},
afterModel(model, transition){
  return model.get('slots');
}
```

The route using some service

```
afterModel(model, transition){
  return this.get('someservice.user.slots');
}
```

Comment: This does not work as expected. I had to adapt a bit of my code, as the route deals with _all_ the users. But there is no change in behavior. The component is rendered multiple times per user. Any other ideas? Could promises be a solution?

Comment: This is the promise route, because we are returning a promise to the afterModel hook it waits for the promise to resolve before continuing on.  From what it sounds like, you have a collection of promises, it would be easiest if you update your question with what your route looks like (and maybe what you tried) that fetches the user and then I'll update the answer with a corresponding solution.